# App crashes after launch on iPad

Tags: ios, air, crash

I'm testing an Air app made for iPad, that crashes right after the splash, however this only happens when I create the .ipa file and I use iTunes to sync it with the device.

If I just run or debug the app directly to the device (I'm using intellij IDEA) it deploys without any issues.

Could be something related to the certificate?, no idea, I know the app installs ok in the device.

I don't know how to check for errors, I saw a link explaining how to do it, but when using XCode.

Answer (score -1):

Well at first, why you use IntelliJ IDEA instead of XCode for an iOS App? Second you are not trying to bugfix a compiled ipa right? You have the source of it? And yes if it crashes right after start it could be a signing error... You need to have valid certificates, provisioning profiles and XCode to compile a signed ipa for Testing

I dont know if IntelliJ IDEA can do something like that, so use XCode, Apple Dev Account and compile it...

Comment: Why do I use IDEA instead of XCode..?, because:

1- I plan to deploy the same app for Android
2- I don't have a mac
3- I rather use AS3 than Objetive-C

Comment: I'm building the app from scratch, of course I have the code.